# regular expression (regex) doesn't working

Tags: java, expression

I pratcing regex, and I have a problem:
I want to check if, if block is correct, meaning

```
if(a,){
```

would return false
and

`if(x, y){`

would return true
I came out with this regular expression :

```
(if|while)\s*(.*)\s*\{.*
```

but this return true on the first example, someone can help me to solve this problem?

Thanks
George

Comment: what should be allowed between the braces, you only check .*

Comment: ups, too fast. (.*) is only a capturing group of anything, no braces are checked, they must be escaped with \

Comment: You will soon see that regular expressions are not the right tool for parsing languages with a rich grammar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem with your regex is that your forgot to escape the brackets :).

Inside the brackets, you are just matching `.*`, which is everything except line endings, which doesn't seem to be what you want.

From your example, I would guess that you want to match those if statements where there is no trailing or leading commas just hanging there. So inside the brackets, this regex should match:

```
\w+\s*(?:\s*,\s*\w+)*
```

Explanation:

If we remove all the `\s*` (they are just there to allow whitespace everywhere), we get

```
\w+(?:,\w+)*
```

Basically, word characters, followed by a bunch of "comma and word characters" thingys. This ensures no comma at the end or the start because the end and start of the pattern are both `\w`.

We can just substitute that into your original regex:

```
(if|while)\s*\(\w+\s*(?:\s*,\s*\w+)*\)\s*\{.*
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mgNdhh/1)

Comment: Thanks, It was almost what I meant,but I was able to modify what you gave to what I meant, thanks for the explaintation and the help

Comment: @Georg So what did you actually mean?

Comment: Maybe I didn't explained my self very well, but I check only the line of the 'if/while', and what you gave allowed if(x){ anything here, and I want it to be only if(x){

Comment: @Georg I see. So you added `^` and `$` at the start and end?

Comment: no, just remove the '.*' at the end, but on a secound thinking, I still need to modify it, because I want to allow that there would at the end '//' and there anything after it. + there is one more problem, it doesn't allow ' if(a == b){ ', I would try to fix it, if I wouldn't be able to, I would write here again.

Comment: plus I want to support this 'if (a || b || c) { ' and this 'if(a && b)} '

Comment: @Georg then regex should not be used here. Use a parser.

Comment: if I would drop the support for ' if(a == b){' , is it still a valid option to use regex ? and there is not need to support spaces, I can remove them easly.

Comment: @Georg There are just too many variations that can happen. Write a parser, or find one online.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Java's misnamed `.matches()` method ... It tries and matches ALL the input.

If you want to see if the regex matches an input text, use a `Pattern`, a `Matcher` and the `.find()` method of the matcher:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-z]");
Matcher m = p.matcher(inputstring);
if (m.find())
    // match
```

If what you want is indeed to see if an input only has lowercase letters, you can use `.matches()`, but you need to match one or more characters: append a `+` to your character class, as in `[a-z]+`. Or use `^[a-z]+$` and `.find()`.